# Error with git archive --remote <repo>

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, git

I installed a Git server with gitosis in Ubuntu 4.10 64 bits. The server works OK, but a user has asked me to run the command **git archive --remote** .

http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-archive

This option Git, so I've read, is disabled and has to be enabled by using **git-daemon**.
http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-daemon

I installed the required package for git-daemon:

**apt-get install git-daemon-run**

And I configured the configuration file /etc/sv/git-daemon/run:

#!/bin/sh

exec 2> & 1

echo 'git-daemon starting.'

exec chpst -ugitdaemon chpst-exec 
   /usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon --verbose --export-all --enable=upload-archive --base-path =/srv/gitosis/git /srv/gitosis/git

Start the service:

**sv up git-daemon**

From the user's PC run:

**$ git archive --remote ssh://gitosis@servername/repository/**

And the following error:

**ERROR: gitosis.serve.main: Unknown command denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

I searched for information and have not found anything. Any idea because it fails?

P.D: Sorry for my English

Comment: Are you trying to run `git archive` against `Github` repositiories by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ssh into the server using the gitosis user?

If not this might be a problem with your ssh keys.

Comment: Yes, I can connect from random PC. In fact, I can work with Git repositories. For example, I can clone a repository on a local machine.

Comment: With the gitosis user, and with keys not password? what is the result if you run: **ssh gitosis@servername /bin/pwd**? Should be something like /home/gitosis.

Comment: On my computer I have the file ~/.ssh/config with the following information:

host servername
     Port 2022    # I configured git server with this port
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key
With this configuration, run:

ssh gitosis@servername /bin/pwd

The following error appears:

ERROR: gitosis.serve.main: Unknown command denied

Comment: If I delete the ~/.ssh/config and run:

ssh -p2022 gitosis@servername /bin/pwd

I enter the password and the screen shows me:

/srv/gitosis

Comment: OK. Then it was the keys.. Go here and follow the guide on how to set it all up: [link](http://git-scm.com/book). See chapter 4.

Comment: But with that key, I can run git clone, git pulls, etc ...
These commands should fail, right?

Comment: This **ssh gitosis@servername /bin/pwd The following error appears: ERROR: gitosis.serve.main: Unknown command denied** == failed login because of keys when the above is true. Sorry, I cant help more without actually doing it hands on, really follow the guide and verify that it is working according to it before looking at other possible problems.